# How to generate a web service client in Java using Eclipse

Tags: java, service

Using Eclipse, what's the best way to generate a web service class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [step-by-step](http://px.pats.no/px/Eclipse_tutorial.html) instruction on how to generate a web service client in eclipse. Note that you'll need the Java EE distribution of Eclipse, and possibly install a JAX-WS implementation (if you don't want to use the one included in the jdk) first (though I think you can have eclipse do that for you).

Answer (score 2):

Most IDE's provide this functionality out of the box. If you're using Netbeans, simply install the webservice plugin and create a new-file using `ctrl+n` and select [New > Other > Web Services > Web Service Client](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html)

Comment: You should _always_ use a wizzard that generate source code (like the one in IntelliJ, haven't tried that in Netbeans), since eventually you need to tweak it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache Axis to generate a Web Service Client. Here is a [link](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#ConsumingWebServicesWithAxis) that can help you out.

Comment: What i will write the web service class? I'm newbie.

Comment: @jtahlborn: Nonsense. JAX-WS is an API standard. To actually use it, you need an implementation like Axis, which does NOT come with the JDK.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt - you can write JAX-WS clients in JDK 6 - see the wsimport executable for generating classes from WSDLs. That said, I've had issues with the implementation's error handling.

Comment: @Michael - jaxws is _certainly_ included in the jdk.  we use both the client and the server from the standard jdk.

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect way to do it. http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/creating-web-service-client-3-steps-using-eclipse. Bear in mind you have to install Axis2 before anything